# Android Flutter how to set App Version build number

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

On Google Play I have my mobile application with version `20220822`. Now I try upload new version with symbol `20220904` but my build is refused by Google play. It looks like app version is not changed in .aab bundle.
I change version in file `BuildConfig.java` to:

```
public static final int VERSION_CODE = 20220904;
```

And in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
version: 0.2.122+20220904
```

but my build still is rejected by Google Play. Where I must change build number?

[image]

Comment: try flutter clean ==> pub get and then create a new build

Answer (score 0):

I found temporary workaround. In file `build.grade` I change automated version to constant value:

```
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 20220905 //flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName "0.2.123" //flutterVersionName
    }
```

As I wrote this in question, my pubspec contains `version: 0.2.122+20220905` but Google Play said that I send version `20220822`.